# New Yocto release is not compatible with Raspberry pi3 model b

Tags: yocto

I just download the new yocto release for my ubuntu PC.
I can build the image under the qumux86, and I saw some new graphical design with the update.
But when I burn the image to raspberrypi 3. 
It is not working. just a black scree. The mouse can move, that's it.

Comment: You have to build the image for the raspberry pi machine. Have you already downloaded meta-raspberrypi and set the machine to 'raspberrypi3'?

Comment: yes, I did. It worked before. But since the yocto released a new version, they changed the gui design for their Linux distribution.

Comment: After that, when I built the image for raspberry pi 3. I can load the GUI in Raspberry. but the kernel drivers works(I set my driver pre-load before load the GUI)